# How to show data in a DetailsView using a query string from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page A with an EDIT LINK. When click it sends a parameter to a second page B, which contains a DetailsView in Edit mode.
Page B take care of editing the details.

```
A.aspx?AuthorId=89
```

My problem is: I am not able to visualize the Right AuthorId passed from page A.aspx in the DetailsView in B.
What I am missing? Please if you have send me a link with some tutorials. Thanks for your time!

Here code for DetailsView -----------

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataKeyNames="AuthorId" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" Height="50px" 
    Width="125px" DefaultMode="Edit">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthorId" HeaderText="AuthorId" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="AuthorId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserId" 
            SortExpression="UserId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NoteInternal" HeaderText="NoteInternal" 
            SortExpression="NoteInternal" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentAuthor" HeaderText="ContentAuthor" 
            SortExpression="ContentAuthor" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EntityDataSource.WhereParameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.whereparameters.aspx)

+
[QueryStringParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim AuthorID as Integer = Request.QueryString("AuthorID") 'vb.net

int AuthorID = Request.QueryString["AuthorID"] ; //c#
```

Comment: sorry how to do it in EntityDataSource as WHERE clause? I think this could be the solution thanks